# Creating sample data (with faker) that has a % overlap in Python

Tags: python, faker

I have 2 tables - customers and purchases

I've used faker to create 100 entries for the customer table with various details of which one is customer_numbers that are unique 5 digits.

I now want to create a table of 100 purchases that reuses the list of customer_numbers but to ensure that there is at least 25% duplicate records.

I am not sure the best way to do this to ensure the 25% requirement.

I initially created a custom function that resamples my original list (using faker.random_elements()) and just takes the first 100 records in the new list but that doesn't ensure a minimum of 25% overlap.

Is there a built in function I can use? If not, what would be the math behind recreating a list with 25% overlaps from an existing list.

Code seems less relevant here but let me know if you need samples.

**Solution I went with(not the only one to the problem)**:

1. Calculated the number of samples to drop list_size-(list-size/(1*repeat rate))
2. Dropped the no of samples from the customer list and resampled from the reduced list the number of samples I dropped (with replacement)
3. Merged the shortened and resampled list

This solution ensures that len(original list) = len(set((new list)))*1.25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I can think of is as follows:

- Randomly selecting a number for your 'guarantee' overlapping between 25 and 100
- Randomly picking the 'guarantee' number of records from the existing list
- Randomly picking the rest of the required records (without considering the existence of the existing list)

This is because your `customer_numbers` consist of 5 digits, therefore picking these 5 digits randomly for 100 times will generally not create any duplicates with the existing list which has only 100 items. So I think using a way to 'guarantee' the overlapping percentage would work reasonably well. Also, I think it would not be difficult to implement the above steps in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solutions! They work and I have done something similar.